# stateless functional components and `react` import

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I face the same issue as described here
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2504

So, any file which has only stateless components needs to have `react` imported like `import React from 'react';`, which is bit annoying (eslint gives error as unused variable; which I understand can be suppressed, still..). Is there a way to avoid having this import in a `webpack` based setup.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. Then, I found this:

[babel-plugin-react-require](https://github.com/vslinko/babel-plugin-react-require)

This will automatically add the required `require` or `import` calls to get `'react'` imported to your stateless component modules.

P.S. If you use webpack and babel6, ensure that you are not using the `jsx-loader` for your JSX files. I was getting errors with this and then I realized the `jsx-loader` is not required anymore. Just use:

[babel-preset-react](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webpack's ProvidePlugin (https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#plugin-provideplugin):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    React: "react"
})
```

Now you'll have React available in every module without having to explicitly write `import React from 'react'`